# Dynamically changing contents of ListCellRenderer

Tags: java, swing, jlist, twitter4j, listcellrenderer

I am attempting to build a twitter client using Twitter4. I am storing the users tweets and info etc in a DefaultListModel in a Jlist. I want to add the users profile picture and to do this I am setting the Icon using a ListCellRenderer. My issue here is that I am only able to set the ListCellRenderer text and icon to one users information. I use a loop to pull down multiple tweets and add them to the model, but the renderer is only setting one tweet many times.

This is the code to retrieve a tweet

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
 Status each = (Status) list.get(i);

                    UI.model.addElement("<html><body style='width: 450px;'>"
                            + "@"
                            + each.getUser().getScreenName()
                            + " - "
                            + each.getText() + "<html><br>");

                    UI.whatIsDisplayedList.setCellRenderer(new newsFeedRenderer(each)); }
```

And this is how I am setting the ListCellRenderer

```
JLabel pic = new JLabel();

        try {
            ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(TwitterFunctions.eachTweetProfilePic(each.getUser()));
            pic.setIcon(img);
            setIcon(img);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        setText( "@" + each.getUser().getScreenName() + " - " + each.getText());
```

What modifications would I have to make to enable the correct formatting of the tweets?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Again, as mentioned in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15488883/applying-a-listcellrenderer-to-individual-cells-on-a-jlist) please create and post an [sscce](http://sscce.org). Please remember that we are all volunteers and so the onus of effort towards answering the question or towards making it easier to answer should be yours. Please read the link.

Comment: @iainmac think of your renderer like a rubber date stamper (https://www.google.com/search?q=date+stamper&hl=en&tbm=isch).  The value you input modifies the output of the renderer, but the same renderer (or rubber stamper) is used for every value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't pass a newFeedReader() to setCellRenderer();
A ListCellRenderer is an object used to paint cells, not to be used as a database kind of object. 
What you're going to want to do is,

- Get all of the statuses at the beginning
- Pass them as an array to a JList
- Then create a custom ListCellRenderer class and in your getListCellRendererComponent method, return your JLabel which has your ListCellRenderer code

Comment: Hi mate, thanks for the reply! Sorry I should have mentioned that newsfeedRenderer is my custom ListCellRenderer class. Could you post a brief example of what you are suggesting? 

Thanks!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels apologies I do not know how to extract and create a sscce with my code. I hope what I have provided is enough for your help. Thanks!

Comment: @iainmac: Come on now. Just create a small compilable runnable program that has a JList and a ListCellRenderer, that we can run and modify. You're basically asking us to do this already, and if you create this first it will make it easier for all of us. I'm sure that you can handle this.